# ZF2 - load configuration from database

Tags: php, configuration, zend-framework2, config

I am solving a problem: I have a ZF2 Skeleton application which runs fine, service manager, db adapter, routing, everything is fine. But what I need to solve is how, when or how better load some configuration (settings) from database?

The point is (AFAIK) to have the Zend configs that are not visible nor editable from outside (or let's say via administration). But I need to have the ability to administer many configuration settings - and these should be loaded also on the startup (bootstrap, whatever). These settings could be managing e.g. widgets displaying (let's assume that almost every block on the website is controlled by widget - view helper - and I have to decide - via configuration - whether to display that widget or with what additional settings).

What I would need to help with is how to manage this configuration that will be loaded from DB.

- should I merge it with Zend config?
- should I load it in module's `onBoostrap`?
- should I use better solution (what)?

I was thinking of having *editable* PHP config file (that will Zend simply load with other config files) so that administering these settings would lead to reading from and writing to a file but this is really a bad idea as there is possibility of more simultaneous edits for which purposes the database handles this far better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `module.php` should have a function `getConfig()` which returns an `array`. You should be able to modify it in such a way to fetch your config key/values from the database.